# Why the DataContext.Connection.ConnectionString can't get the password

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
class Program
{
    private const string Sqlconnstr = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog = LINQtoSQL;UID = Scarface;PWD = kaka1983513!;";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataContext = new DataContext(Sqlconnstr);
        var books = dataContext.GetTable<Book>();
        var query = from book in books
                    select book;
        var list = query.ToList();  //If i uncomment this line,i can't get the full string without 'PWD = 123456'.
        Console.WriteLine(dataContext.Connection.ConnectionString);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

How can I get the full string with `'PWD = 123456'` after `query.ToList()` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you would need to read the connection information back out, but I think what you're falling foul of is [PersistSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When set to false or no (strongly recommended), security-sensitive information, such as the password, is not returned as part of the connection if the connection is open or has ever been in an open state. Resetting the connection string resets all connection string values including the password. Recognized values are **true**, **false**, **yes**, and **no**.

The default value for this connection string parameter is `false`.

Comment: Thank you,you are right.I add 'Persist Security Info = true' in the connection string,i can get the password.This is a problem that i use 'LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer'.